# Why If I obtain a SharedPreferences in an NotificationListener always is true?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an Fragment with a Switch where I put the value of shared preferences:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editorSharedPreferences = sharedPref.edit();
}

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);

    activate_notifications = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch_activate_notifications);
    activate_notifications.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i("onChecked",String.valueOf(isChecked));
            editorSharedPreferences.putBoolean(getString(R.string.sharedpref_notif),isChecked);
            editorSharedPreferences.commit();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

And this is the NotificationListener where I get the value:

```
    @Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i("Msg", "Notification Posted");
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();

    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title = String.valueOf(extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE));
    String text = String.valueOf(extras.getCharSequence("android.text"));
    int id = sbn.getId();
    String TAG = String.valueOf(sbn.getTag());

    boolean isNotificationActivated = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.sharedpref_notif),false);

    if(isNotificationActivated) {

        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("id", id);
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
        msgrcv.putExtra("TAG", TAG);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);

    }

}
```

I don't know why the value of the shared preferences is always true when I get him in the notificationlistener. :(

Comment: because you get the shared preferece instance in 2 different ways..`getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`. pick one way and stick to it

Comment: And also `getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` is for the activity only use. `getSharedPreferences` to get throught out your app!

Comment: Thank you @tyczj that's was the problem!